# FCN32 Model is not converging and loss is fluctuating after some points. Why?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, image-segmentation, pycaffe

I am trying to train fcn32. I am training [voc-fcn32s](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/tree/master/voc-fcn32s) model for my own data that has imbalanced class number. This is the learning curve for 18,000 iterations:
[image]

As you can see training is diminishing in some points and then it is fluctuating. I read some online recommendations that they are suggesting reducing the learning rate or changing the bias value in convolution layers for fillers. So, what I did, is that I changed the [train_val.prototxt](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc-fcn32s/train.prototxt) as follows for these two layers:

```
 .... 
layer {
      name: "score_fr"
      type: "Convolution"
      bottom: "fc7"
      top: "score_fr"
      param {
        lr_mult: 1
        decay_mult: 1
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 2
        decay_mult: 0
      }
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 5 # the number of classes
        pad: 0
        kernel_size: 1
        weight_filler {
            type: "xavier"
        }   
        bias_filler {
            type: "constant"
            value: 0.5 #+
        } 
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "upscore"
      type: "Deconvolution"
      bottom: "score_fr"
      top: "upscore"
      param {
        lr_mult: 0
      }
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 5 # the number of classes
        bias_term: true   #false
        kernel_size: 64
        stride: 32
        group: 5 #2
        weight_filler: { 
             type: "bilinear" 
             value:0.5   #+
        }
      }
    }
....
```

And this the trend of model
[image]

It seems not much thing has changed in the behavior of the model.

1) Am doing the right way to add these values to `weight_filler`?

2) Should I change the learning policy in the solver from `fixed` to `step` by reducing by the factor of 10 each time? Will it help to tackle this issue?

I am worried that I am doing the wrong things and my model cannot converge. Does anyone have any suggestion about this? What important things I should consider while training model? What kind of changes can I do on `solver` and `train_val` that model to be converged?

I really appreciate your help.

**More details after adding BatchNorm layer**

Thanks @Shai and @Jonathan for suggesting to add `batchNorm` layers. 
I added `Batch Normalization Layers` before `reLU` layers, this one sample layer:

```
layer {
  name: "conv1_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1_1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 100
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "bn1_1"
  type: "BatchNorm"
  bottom: "conv1_1"
  top: "bn1_1"
  batch_norm_param {
    use_global_stats: false
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
}
layer {
  name: "bn1_1"
  type: "BatchNorm"
  bottom: "conv1_1"
  top: "bn1_1"
  batch_norm_param {
    use_global_stats: true
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "scale1_1"
  type: "Scale"
  bottom: "bn1_1"
  top: "bn1_1"
  scale_param {
     bias_term: true
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "bn1_1"
  top: "bn1_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv1_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "bn1_1"
  top: "conv1_2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
  }
}
```

As far as I knew from docs, I can only add one parameter in Batch normalization  instead of three since I have single channel images. Is this my understanding true? as follows:

```
param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
```

Should I add more parameters to scale layer, as documentation is mentioning? What are the meaning of these parameters in `Scale` layer? like:

```
layer { bottom: 'layerx-bn' top: 'layerx-bn' name: 'layerx-bn-scale' type: 'Scale',
  scale_param { 
    bias_term: true
    axis: 1      # scale separately for each channel
    num_axes: 1  # ... but not spatially (default)
    filler { type: 'constant' value: 1 }           # initialize scaling to 1
    bias_filler { type: 'constant' value: 0.001 }  # initialize bias
}}
```

and this is [image: the drawing] of the network. I am not sure how much I am wrong/right. Have I added correctly?
The other question is about [debug_info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510706/how-to-interpret-caffe-log-with-debug-info). What is the meaning of these lines of log file after activating `debug_info`? What does it mean of `diff` and `data`? And why the values are 0? Is my net working correctly?

```
 I0123 23:17:49.498327 15230 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 50, loss = 105465
    I0123 23:17:49.498337 15230 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 0.643982
    I0123 23:17:49.498349 15230 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #1: loss = 105446 (* 1 = 105446 loss)
    I0123 23:17:49.498359 15230 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 50, lr = 1e-11
    I0123 23:19:12.680325 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer data, top blob data data: 34.8386
    I0123 23:19:12.680615 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer data_data_0_split, top blob data_data_0_split_0 data: 34.8386
    I0123 23:19:12.680670 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer data_data_0_split, top blob data_data_0_split_1 data: 34.8386
    I0123 23:19:12.680778 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer label, top blob label data: 0
    I0123 23:19:12.680829 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer label_label_0_split, top blob label_label_0_split_0 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:12.680896 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer label_label_0_split, top blob label_label_0_split_1 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:12.688591 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer conv1_1, top blob conv1_1 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:12.688695 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer conv1_1, param blob 0 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:12.688742 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer conv1_1, param blob 1 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:12.721791 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer bn1_1, top blob bn1_1 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:12.721853 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer bn1_1, param blob 0 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:12.721890 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer bn1_1, param blob 1 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:12.721901 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer bn1_1, param blob 2 data: 96.1127    
    I0123 23:19:12.996196 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer scale4_1, param blob 0 data: 1
    I0123 23:19:12.996237 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer scale4_1, param blob 1 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:12.996939 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer relu4_1, top blob bn4_1 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.012020 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer conv4_2, top blob conv4_2 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.012403 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer conv4_2, param blob 0 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.012446 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer conv4_2, param blob 1 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.015959 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer bn4_2, top blob bn4_2 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.016005 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer bn4_2, param blob 0 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.016046 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer bn4_2, param blob 1 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.016054 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer bn4_2, param blob 2 data: 96.1127
    I0123 23:19:13.017211 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer scale4_2, top blob bn4_2 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.017251 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer scale4_2, param blob 0 data: 1
    I0123 23:19:13.017292 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer scale4_2, param blob 1 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.017980 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer relu4_2, top blob bn4_2 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.032080 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer conv4_3, top blob conv4_3 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.032452 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer conv4_3, param blob 0 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.032493 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer conv4_3, param blob 1 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.036018 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer bn4_3, top blob bn4_3 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.036064 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer bn4_3, param blob 0 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.036105 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer bn4_3, param blob 1 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.036114 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer bn4_3, param blob 2 data: 96.1127
    I0123 23:19:13.038148 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer scale4_3, top blob bn4_3 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.038189 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer scale4_3, param blob 0 data: 1
    I0123 23:19:13.038230 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer scale4_3, param blob 1 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.038969 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer relu4_3, top blob bn4_3 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.039417 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer pool4, top blob pool4 data: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.043354 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer conv5_1, top blob conv5_1 data: 0

    I0123 23:19:13.128515 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer score_fr, top blob score_fr data: 0.000975524
    I0123 23:19:13.128569 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer score_fr, param blob 0 data: 0.0135222
    I0123 23:19:13.128607 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer score_fr, param blob 1 data: 0.000975524
    I0123 23:19:13.129696 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer upscore, top blob upscore data: 0.000790174
    I0123 23:19:13.129734 15230 net.cpp:620]     [Forward] Layer upscore, param blob 0 data: 0.25
    I0123 23:19:13.130656 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer score, top blob score data: 0.000955503
    I0123 23:19:13.130709 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer score_score_0_split, top blob score_score_0_split_0 data: 0.000955503
    I0123 23:19:13.130754 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer score_score_0_split, top blob score_score_0_split_1 data: 0.000955503
    I0123 23:19:13.146767 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer accuracy, top blob accuracy data: 1
    I0123 23:19:13.148967 15230 net.cpp:608]     [Forward] Layer loss, top blob loss data: 105320
    I0123 23:19:13.149173 15230 net.cpp:636]     [Backward] Layer loss, bottom blob score_score_0_split_1 diff: 0.319809
    I0123 23:19:13.149323 15230 net.cpp:636]     [Backward] Layer score_score_0_split, bottom blob score diff: 0.319809
    I0123 23:19:13.150310 15230 net.cpp:636]     [Backward] Layer score, bottom blob upscore diff: 0.204677
    I0123 23:19:13.152452 15230 net.cpp:636]     [Backward] Layer upscore, bottom blob score_fr diff: 253.442
    I0123 23:19:13.153218 15230 net.cpp:636]     [Backward] Layer score_fr, bottom blob bn7 diff: 9.20469
    I0123 23:19:13.153254 15230 net.cpp:647]     [Backward] Layer score_fr, param blob 0 diff: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.153291 15230 net.cpp:647]     [Backward] Layer score_fr, param blob 1 diff: 20528.8
    I0123 23:19:13.153420 15230 net.cpp:636]     [Backward] Layer drop7, bottom blob bn7 diff: 9.21666
    I0123 23:19:13.153554 15230 net.cpp:636]     [Backward] Layer relu7, bottom blob bn7 diff: 0
    I0123 23:19:13.153856 15230 net.cpp:636]     [Backward] Layer scale7, bottom blob bn7 diff: 0
   E0123 23:19:14.382714 15230 net.cpp:736]     [Backward] All net params (data, diff): L1 norm = (19254.6, 102644); L2 norm = (391.485, 57379.6)
```

I really appreciate if someone knows, please share ideas/links/resources here. Thanks again

Comment: IMHO, I don't think adding `bias_term` to `"Deconvolution"` layer is a good idea. Do you have [`"BatchNorm"` layers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41608242/1714410) in your model? What activation are you using on top of the linear units, `"ReLU"`? Have you tried setting [`debug_info: true`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510706/how-to-interpret-caffe-log-with-debug-info) and inspecting the debug log?

Comment: @Shai Thank you so much for editing and for your recommendations. No I have not changed the FCN model that much since I am not familiar enough with layers and their architectures. You are right, changing `bias_term` did not change anything on the output. May I ask what is the exact purpose of `BatchNorm` layer? Is it normalizing data? Would it be necessary since I have already normalized my images between 0-1 before creating LMDB database?Another question is how much freedom we have to change the architecture of a model?

Comment: @S.EB I added some information on Batch Normalization in my answer. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608242/how-should-batchnorm-layer-be-used-in-caffe. If you have additional questions, you might want to ask separate questions.

Comment: @Shai thank you very much for your comments

Comment: Your question became quite big. You might consider asking several smaller more focused questions? @S.EB

Answer (score 2):

I would not expect changing the bias values to help with the training. The first thing I would try is lowering the learning rate. You can do this manually by retraining the the weights that have reached a plateau and use a solver with a lower base_lr. Or you can change your solver.prototxt to use a different update policy. You can either set the method to step or you can use an update policy such as Adam. See:

http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/solver.html

As [@Shai recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41735132/fcn32-model-is-not-converging-and-loss-is-fluctuating-after-some-points-why#comment70665511_41735132), adding `"BatchNorm"` layers should help. Batch Normalization is similar to "whitening"/normalizing the input data, but is applied to the intermediate layers. The paper on Batch normalization is on [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167).

You should also reserve some data for validation. Just looking at the training loss can be misleading.

Comment: Jonathan and Shai Thanks for your help, I will try and I will edit and bring the results here.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `"BatchNorm"` parameters:
This layer has three internal parameters: (0) mean, (1) variance, and (2) moving average factor, **regardless** of the number of channels or the shape of your blob. Therefore, if you wish to explicitly set `lr_mult` you need to define it for all three.

Regarding the zeros in the log:
Please [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40510706/1714410) on how to read caffe's debug log.
It seems like you are training your model from scratch (not fine tuning) and that all weights are set to zero. This is a very poor initialization strategy.
Please consider defining `filler`s and `bias_filler`s for initializing the weights.