# Caffe accuracy drops when testing as compared to training on same dataset

Tags: caffe, pycaffe, batch-normalization

I am having issues with the Caffe BatchNorm layer during testing phase. At least I assume it's related to the BatchNorm layer This question already came up a couple of times, but I still found no solution that works for me.

Everything looks fine during training but during testing the accuracy goes down dramatically (on the same dataset). I also asked in the google group but got no answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/0t4jehvN6oQ There you will also find my network.prototxt

I'm using BatchNorm in a U-Net segmentation network. During testing I use a batch size of 1, but this should not affect the result when "use_global_stats = true", right?

I basically tried all variants discussed in [How should "BatchNorm" layer be used in caffe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608242/how-should-batchnorm-layer-be-used-in-caffe) but nothing works.

Can anyone help?

Peter