# How to modify batch normalization layers (DeconvNet) to be able to run with caffe?

Tags: caffe, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, pycaffe, batch-normalization

I wanted to run the [Deconvnet](http://cvlab.postech.ac.kr/research/deconvnet/model/DeconvNet/DeconvNet_inference_deploy.prototxt) on my data, however it seemd it has been written for another version of `caffe`. Does anyone know how to change `batch_params`?

The one that is in Deconvnet

```
layers { bottom: 'conv1_1' top: 'conv1_1' name: 'bn1_1' type: BN
  bn_param { scale_filler { type: 'constant' value: 1 }
             shift_filler { type: 'constant' value: 0.001 }
             bn_mode: INFERENCE } }
```

And the one that Caffe provides for `cifar10` example:

```
layer {
  name: "bn1"
  type: "BatchNorm"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "bn1"
  batch_norm_param {
    use_global_stats: true
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
```

Once I wanted to run it show me the following error first:

```
I1029 13:46:47.156885 11601 solver.cpp:87] Creating training net from net file: train_val.prototxt
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:299] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 59:3: Unknown enumeration value of "BN" for field "type".
F1029 13:46:47.157971 11601 upgrade_proto.cpp:88] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param)
```

and after changing `BN` into `BatchNorm`, it shows new error about parameters:

```
I1029 14:03:38.497725 12097 solver.cpp:87] Creating training net from net file: train_val.prototxt
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:299] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 59:3: Unknown enumeration value of "BatchNorm" for field "type".
F1029 14:03:38.503345 12097 upgrade_proto.cpp:88] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param)
```

Has anyone tried to train Deconvnet? if yes could you please guide me?
Thanks

Comment: it seems like you are using old caffe version. please rebase to latest `master` version and then try with `type: "BatchNorm"`

Comment: As for the scale and bias/shift, you need to add an additional `"Scale"` layer. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41608242/1714410) for more information.

Comment: I installed 3 months ago almost from the master branch of caffe website. Thanks for help. Will try

Comment: It seems like your caffe is regarding `"type"` as an enumeration rather than as a string: enumeration was used in older versions and is no longer used.

Comment: the first one is from `Deconvnet` which I have not changed, I just wanted to know what kind of changes should I do on their code. My caffe version is `1.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please let me know if this is correct to change like this?

```
layer {
  name: "bn1_1"
  type: "BatchNorm"
  bottom: "conv1_1"
  top: "conv1_1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  batch_norm_param {
    use_global_stats: true
  }
}
layer {
  name: "scale_conv1_1"
  type: "Scale"
  bottom: "conv1_1"
  top: "conv1_1"
  scale_param {
    bias_term: true
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.001
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what about filler for the scale?

Comment: Dear Shai, I am creating the layers by `caffe.NetSpec()` , so I wrote like this `scale=L.Scale(conv,in_place=True,bias_term=1,bias_filler=dict(type='constant', value=0.001))`. How can I add it, I thought its value is `1` so scale is not changing, am I wrong?