# Expected integer or identifier, got: "ReLU"

Tags: neural-network, caffe, image-segmentation

I am trying to run [Deconvnet](http://cvlab.postech.ac.kr/research/deconvnet/model/DeconvNet/DeconvNet_inference_deploy.prototxt) on my data, My caffe version is from here

It is showing the parser error:

```
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:299] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 147:9: Expected integer or identifier, got: "ReLU"
F1030 12:11:39.002427  7017 upgrade_proto.cpp:88] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: train_val.prototxt
```

I tried many things such as `"RELU"`, `"ReLU"` and `'ReLU'`...however it did not work,
I really do not know what to do with this. I really appreciate if someone knows what is the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try: `type: "ReLU"`

Comment: I have tried that one too :(( as you can see above

Comment: But your file (Deconvnet link) is missing the quotes. Here, take a look at a ReLU layer: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html. Oh! Also, you have *layers* instead of *layer* (layer**s** is deprecated and may be causing trouble).

Comment: it seems like you are using two versions of caffe: one that expects new proto version (with layer types defined through a **string**) and an old version (with layer types defined through **enumeration**). It will also solve your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47001337/1714410).

Comment: @grovina Thanks for the comment, I should have shared my `train_val.prototxt`. I had already done those refinements including quotes ("ReLU") and changing layers to `layer`. I really do not understand what is the issue.

Comment: I even sent a network to the same caffe and it is running very well with `"ReLU"`, I do not know what is the reason, Can be because of indentation?